# Display an image or UIImage with a plain CALayer

Tags: ios, iphone, performance, uiimage, core-animation

I've often read that using a `CALayer` rather than a `UIImageView` is an performance boost when it comes to heavy image usage. That makes sense, because `UIImageView` causes 3 copies of the image in memory, which is needed for Core Animation. But in my case I don't use Core Animation.

How can I assign a `UIImage` (or its image data) to a `CALayer` and then display it?

Comment: Where have you read this?  UIViews in general are lightweight wrappers around CALayers, and I've not seen much of a difference between them in regards to memory or display performance.  I'm also not sure if I buy the 3 copies of an image in memory argument.  In any case, CALayers are indeed part of Core Animation (thus the CA prefix).

Answer (score 55):

```
UIImage*    backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:kBackName];
CALayer*    aLayer = [CALayer layer];
CGFloat nativeWidth = CGImageGetWidth(backgroundImage.CGImage);
CGFloat nativeHeight = CGImageGetHeight(backgroundImage.CGImage);
CGRect      startFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, nativeWidth, nativeHeight);
aLayer.contents = (id)backgroundImage.CGImage;
aLayer.frame = startFrame;
```

or in a Swift playground (you will have to provide your own PNG image in the Playground's resource file. I'm using the example of "FrogAvatar".)

```
  //: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
import UIKit

if let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "FrogAvatar") // you will have to provide your own image in your playground's Resource file
{
    let height = backgroundImage.size.height
    let width = backgroundImage.size.width

    let aLayer = CALayer()
    let startFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

    let aView = UIView(frame: startFrame)
    aLayer.frame = startFrame
    aLayer.contentsScale = aView.contentScaleFactor
    aLayer.contents = backgroundImage.cgImage
    aView.layer.addSublayer(aLayer)
    aView // look at this via the Playground's  eye icon
}
```

[image: An image as the content of a CALayer embedded in a UIView]

Comment: thanks! why do you write (id)backgroundImage and not just backgroundImage? Shouldn't the compiler recognize that you have a UIImage there? Or is the CGImage property otherwise not recognized? Maybe an missing import?

Comment: I tried it. The most interesting thins is missing though: How to get it on screen? I want to avoid an UIViews as much as possible.

Comment: You'll need to add the CALayer as a sublayer of some UIView's layer.  Each layer does not need its own view, but the layer hierarchy does need to reside in a view somewhere so that it can be drawn to the screen.

Comment: The cast to id is needed because CGImageRef is not defined in the headers as descending from id, but that is how the contents property of CALayer is defined.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that you should divide native image size by `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`

Answer (score 12):

ARC version requires a different cast:

```
self.myView.layer.contents = (__bridge id) self.myImage.CGImage;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CALayer *layer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
layer.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)([UIImage imageNamed:@"REWIFISocketOff"].CGImage);
```

Comment: This answer would be significantly improved if you were to include an explanation rather than just code