# Image in CAShapeLayer do not fit in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cashapelayer

I made a Circle shape by UIBezierPath and then make it to a CAShapeLayer that can be dragged. In addition, I added a PNG Image (30px, 30px) to my xcode project.
I added the PNG Image to the CAShapeLayer, but everytime I move it 'cuts' and some parts of the ball can not be seen:
[image]

This is the PNG Image:

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

var shapeLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()
var circlePath2 = UIBezierPath()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

let angleEarth: Double = 0
        let angleEarthAfterCalculate: CGFloat = CGFloat(angleEarth*M_PI/180) - CGFloat(M_PI/2)
        let earthX = midViewX + cos(angleEarthAfterCalculate)*100
        let earthY = midViewY + sin(angleEarthAfterCalculate)*100
        circlePath2 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: earthX,y: earthY), radius: CGFloat(10), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
        shapeLayer2.path = circlePath2.CGPath
        shapeLayer2.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        shapeLayer2.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        shapeLayer2.lineWidth = 7
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer2)
let dragBall = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(ViewController.dragBall(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(dragBall)

let image = UIImage(named: "rrr.png")
            if let realImage = image {
            let color = UIColor(patternImage: image!)
            shapeLayer2.fillColor = color.CGColor
            shapeLayer4.fillColor = color.CGColor
}

 @IBAction func dragBall(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
            let point = recognizer.locationInView(self.view)
            let earthX = Double(point.x)
            let earthY = Double(point.y)
            let midViewXDouble = Double(midViewX)
            let midViewYDouble = Double(midViewY)
            let angleX = (earthX - midViewXDouble)
            let angleY = (earthY - midViewYDouble)
            angle = atan2(angleY, angleX)
            let earthX2 = midViewXDouble + cos(angle)*100
            let earthY2 = midViewYDouble + sin(angle)*100
            circlePath2 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: earthX2,y: earthY2), radius: CGFloat(10), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
            shapeLayer2.path = circlePath2.CGPath
}
```

**Shortcut: I can't fit the PNG Image to the CAShapeLayer without getting the result in the gif.**

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29279474/swift-add-image-to-cashapelayer?rq=1 ?

Comment: @UmairAfzal Yes, the first example of his answer is in my code, the second doesn't work

Comment: and this one ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272512/add-uiimage-in-calayer?lq=1

Comment: Yea I tried, it didn't work. I probably tried everything on Google

Comment: My guess is that the bounds/frame of the layer is off. It's size seems to be the whole size of your big circle bounds and that's why you see "black parts", it just made a pattern with you image.

Comment: @Larme How can I fix it?

Comment: What are your desire results of adding the image to the CAShapeLayer?

Comment: @fragilecat You can see it in the gif

Comment: @Eliko, the gif shows your current problem right? If everything was working correctly what would we see?

Comment: @fragilecat You would see the PNG Image when I move it, instead of some white cuts

Comment: Ok then you should resize your image to the same size as the CAShapeLayer bounds. If you look at the documentation for UIColor(patternImage) it informs you that the image will be tiled to cover the given area.

Comment: Where are midViewX, midViewY and angle defined?